# How to add ng-pattern in mvc @Html.TextBoxFor(...)?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I get an error for ng-pattern...how can i add it in `@Html.TextBoxFor`? I tried with ng-pattern also but same result...it throw me an error...i know that is for ng-model in mvc i need to use ng_model but for ng-pattern is not working

```
    div class="form-group">
    <label for="licencenumber" class="control-label col-lg-5 col-md-6">@Html.Label(@Translator.Translate("LICENCE_NUMBER")): <span id="licenceNumberRequired" class="required display">*</span></label>
  <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-6">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DocumentNumber, new { @class = "form-control", id = "documentNumber", @maxlength = "13", ng_model="documentNumber",ng_pattern="^/[\w ]+$/" })

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - "Include any error messages, key APIs, or unusual circumstances that make your question different from similar questions already on the site"

Comment: i just need to know how to add ng-pattern in @Html.TextBoxFor.... what else do u need?

Comment: what error is being thrown?  is it server or client side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a problem with .NET hitting an unknown escape sequence in the string.  Try adding the ng-pattern like this:

```
ng_pattern = @"/[\w ]+$/"
```

with the @ character before the string.  That should cause it to ignore escape sequences